# JSON nested schema reference using Retrofit 2

Tags: java, android, json, mongoose, retrofit

I'm relative new to Retrofit 2 and Android/Backend programming and I'm wondering how to correctly convert my JSON schemas to Java for an android school project.

So the situation is I need a couple of "Challenges" in my app. 
The current structure is kinda complicated, I'm not even sure if we're working correctly but I'll give it a shot here.

These are my mongoose schema's on our REST backend:

Challenge: so this object holds all the normal attributes and a reference to challengeType aswel, since our challenge is defined by polymorphism.

```
var ChallengeSchema = new Schema({
_id: ObjectId,
name: String,
description: [String],
challengeType:{
    type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'ChallengeType'
},
state: Number,
difficulty: Number
});
```

Now our challengeTypes are defined as:

```
var ChallengeTypeSchema = new Schema({
    _id: ObjectId
}),
  RecipeChallengeSchema = new Schema({
    _id: ObjectId,
    joined: Number,
    dietTypeMaker: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'DietTypeMaker'
    }
}),
  FastfoodChallengeSchema = new Schema({
    _id: ObjectId,
    joined: Number
}),
  ThursdayVeggieDayChallengeSchema = new Schema({
    _id: ObjectId,
    joined: Number,
    dietTypeMaker1: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'DietTypeMaker'
    },
    dietTypeMaker2: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'DietTypeMaker'
    }
}),
  RestaurantChallengeSchema = new Schema({
    _id: ObjectId,
    joined: Number,
    city: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'City'
    },
    restaurantTypeMaker: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'RestaurantTypeMaker'
    }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('ChallengeType',ChallengeTypeSchema,'challengeTypes');
module.exports = mongoose.model('RecipeChallenge', RecipeChallengeSchema, 'challengeTypes', ['ChallengeType']);
module.exports = mongoose.model('FastfoodChallenge', FastfoodChallengeSchema, 'challengeTypes', ['RecipeChallenge']);
module.exports = mongoose.model('ThursdayVeggieDayChallenge', ThursdayVeggieDayChallengeSchema, 'challengeTypes', ['RecipeChallenge']);
module.exports = mongoose.model('RestaurantChallenge', RestaurantChallengeSchema, 'challengeTypes', ['ChallengeType']);
```

These are linked with DietTypeMaker or RestaurantTypeMaker which determines our recipes or restaurants depending of the challenge that is active.

```
var RestaurantTypeMakerSchema = new Schema({
_id: ObjectId,
eatingPlace: {
    restaurants: [
        {
            type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Restaurant'
        }
    ]
},
gastronomic: {
    restaurants: [
        {
            type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Restaurant'
        }
    ]
},
snackbar: {
    restaurants: [
        {
            type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Restaurant'
        }
    ]
},
catering: {
    restaurants: [
        {
            type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Restaurant'
        }
    ]
}
});
```

and

```
var DietTypeMakerSchema = new Schema({
_id: ObjectId,
vegetarian: {
    recipe: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Recipe'
    }
},
glutenFree: {
    recipe: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Recipe'
    }
},
sugarFree: {
    recipe: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Recipe'
    }
},
childFriendly: {
    recipe: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Recipe'
    }
}
});
```

each of which refer to a recipe or a restaurant:

```
var RecipeSchema = new Schema({
_id: ObjectId,
title: String,
difficultyRate: Number,
ingredients: [
    {
        name: String,
        qty: String
    }
],
description: [String],
extraInfo: {
    preparationTime: Number,
    cookDifficulty: Number,
    recipeType: Number,
    dietTypes: [Number],
    isFastFood: Boolean
},
image: {
    data: Buffer, contentType: String
}
});
```

and

```
var RestaurantSchema = new Schema({
_id: ObjectId,
name: String,
streetName: String,
houseNumber: Number,
city: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'City'
},
restaurantTypes: [Number],
preferences: [Number],
websiteLink: String,
emailaddress: String,
description: [String]
});
```

This all needs to be converted into java code for our app. Now I know how to make pojos, I've made them for recipe and restaurant. And I am able to get them correctly from my backend using Retrofit 2. Now the thing I'm stuck on is the complex structure we have with all the schema references...

Are we making things to complicated or is this even possible...???